# PhantomJS throws "Unable to access network" in TeamCity

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, teamcity

I'm testing an AngularJS application and I've set up [PhantomJS 2.0](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphantomjs.org%2F&ei=E-svVbHHJOHfywPL2ICAAw&usg=AFQjCNHjmSDDvf80K-7-PG7d3ghScyDhfA&sig2=eI9Q8S9j8jFojzSD-3Cdyw&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGQ) to be executed in my TeamCity configration together with [Jasmine 2.2](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html).

The step in TeamCity is of type Command Line.
It points to the PhantomJS executable, and has two parameters set:

```
path\to\run-jasmine.js other\path\specRunner.html
```

When the build step is executed I get the following error in TeamCity:

> "Unable to access network"

I've also tried to run it locally with cmd:

`phantomjs.exe \different\path\run-jasmine.js other\path\specRunner.html`

However I get the same error message...

Any ideas why this error is thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I had to specify the paths with **"/"** rather than **"\"** .

This was the correct approach:

```
path/to/run-jasmine.js path/to/SpecRunner.html
```